# Change specific word in HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to chane averey word "morr" in the HTML using JavaScript. I'm not allowed to touch the HTML so i cant use span or id. Can anyone help me? Here's the HTML:

### Morrhår

Är katten skrämd lägger den morrhåren bakåt, detsamma gör den vid slagsmål för att skydda morrhåren. Om katten är nyfiken vinklar den morrhåren framåt.

Comment: <h2>Morrhår</h2>
<p><img src="http://blogg.wikki.se/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/catbyBaikal.jpg" align="right">
Är <span>katt</span>en skrämd lägger den morrhåren bakåt, detsamma gör den vid slagsmål för att skydda morrhåren. Om <span>katt</span>en är nyfiken vinklar den morrhåren framåt.
</p>

Comment: You forgot the HTML, you just posted plain text, edit the question please

Comment: Posted it in the comment

Comment: Really I am not getting what your requirement is.. Are you saying that you want to replace the "morr" occurence everywhere in your html or is it limited to certain tags?

Comment: It's everywhere yes. But the entire text is inside a Div id if thats helping.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get the text from the html

```js
let text = document.querySelector('.text').textContent;

let result = text.replace(/morrhåren/gi, 'testttttttttttttttttttttttttt');

document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<p class="text">
  Är katten skrämd lägger den morrhåren bakåt, detsamma gör den vid slagsmål för att skydda morrhåren. Om katten är nyfiken vinklar den morrhåren framåt
   Är katten skrämd lägger den morrhåren bakåt, detsamma gör den vid slagsmål för att skydda morrhåren. Om katten är nyfiken vinklar den morrhåren framåt
    Är katten skrämd lägger den morrhåren bakåt, detsamma gör den vid slagsmål för att skydda morrhåren. Om katten är nyfiken vinklar den morrhåren framåt.
</p>
<div class="result"></div>
```

and if you have the text as a string in javascript

```js
let longString = `Är katten skrämd lägger den morrhåren bakåt, detsamma gör den vid slagsmål för att skydda morrhåren. Om katten är nyfiken vinklar den morrhåren framåt.`;

let result = longString.replace(/morrhåren/gi, 'testttttttttt');

document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: But in this case you have hardcoded the text

Comment: please check the code above you can grab all the text you want from the html and then select it in js and replace any word you want as its in the snippet